# Huggingface - Dropout layer in the TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification pretrained model

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

What is the objective of the Dropout layer in the TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification pretrained model and why the last layer is not softmax or sigmoid?

The TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification pretrained model has Dropout layer at the last.

```
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer, 
    # loss=self.model.compute_loss,
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics = ["accuracy"]  
)
model.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
distilbert (TFDistilBertMain multiple                  66362880  
_________________________________________________________________
pre_classifier (Dense)       multiple                  590592    
_________________________________________________________________
classifier (Dense)           multiple                  1538      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_99 (Dropout)         multiple                  0         <------------
=================================================================
Total params: 66,955,010
Trainable params: 592,130
Non-trainable params: 66,362,880
```

To feed output into the categorical or logistic cross-entropy loss layer, I believe the output is from softmax or sigmoid. However the last layer is dropout. Please help understand the reason.

## Reference

[Fine-tuning with native PyTorch/TensorFlow](https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#fine-tuning-with-native-pytorch-tensorflow)

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification

model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(16), epochs=3, batch_size=16)
```

Comment: The last layer showed by the summary is not necessarily the output of the model. To check the outputs of the model, you should use the `model.outputs` attribute.